# The listener to isSignedIn is getting fired multiple times while implementing google oauth 2.0 implicit signing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-oauth

The problem I am having is that

```
auth.isSignedIn.listen((isLoggedIn) => ...
```

in init() function is firing multiple times. As I log in & out without refreshing, the number of times it fires keeps on increasing. I have added the console log image below. The message 'how many times' should print only once.

[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/150jo.png)

Below are my program files

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import GoogleOauth from './components/googleOauth.js'

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isLoggedin: false
    }
    this.logoutFunc = this.logoutFunc.bind(this)
    this.init = this.init.bind(this)
    this.signin = this.signin.bind(this)
  }

  logoutFunc () {
    console.log('clicked logout')
    window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      const auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
      auth.signOut()
      this.setState({
        isLoggedin: !this.state.isLoggedin
      })
    })
  }

  loadScript () {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js'
    script.onload = this.init
    script.id = 'google-login'
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    console.log('is it the componentWillMount')
    this.loadScript()
  }

  signin () {
    console.log('clicked signin')
    this.init()
    this.logoutFunc()
  }

  init () {
    window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      const auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
      auth.isSignedIn.listen((isLoggedIn) => {
        const profile = auth.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile()
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          console.log('how many times')
        }
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
          <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
          <h1 className='App-title'>Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className='App-intro'>
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <GoogleOauth logoutFunc={this.logoutFunc} signin={this.signin} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

googleOauth.js

```
import React from 'react'

const GoogleOauth = ({logoutFunc, signin}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='g-signin2' data-onsuccess='onSignIn' onClick={signin} data-width='94' data-height='36' />
      <button onClick={logoutFunc}> logout </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default GoogleOauth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling init multiple times (and thus adding the listener multiple times). Add a variable to check if it was already called and skip it when this is the case.

Comment: Actually init() is not getting called multilple times. I had added a console log inside init before the listener. The init() gets called only once but the listener logs multiple times.

Comment: Oh! I now understand what you are saying. ignore my previous comment.

Comment: I do not need to init() when I click the signin button. It is attaching another listener.